# How to use $in with Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

How I setup my data in an rspec

```
let(:first_origin) { create(:origin, owner: "123@tenant") }
let(:second_origin) { create(:origin, owner: "123@tenant") }

create_list(:ticket, 10, origin: first_origin)
create_list(:ticket, 10, origin: second_origin)
create_list(:ticket, 5)
```

The model `ticket` belongs_to `origin`.
What I want to accomplish is query all tickets with owner "123@tenant", using `origin_id` and `$in`.
My query is failry simple:

```
query.in(origin_id: origins)
```

where origins is an array of the two IDs (tried both the $oid and `to_s` to have an array of strings.
It always returns all `Ticket`s, count is 25, should be 20. If I try to loop over the results and print `origin_id` I can clearly see that all `origin_id` are included and the total count is 25. I've tried `where(:origin_id.in => origins)` as well, same thing.

Latest `mongoid` and `mongodb`, latest ruby.

I'm sure it's my fault, but can't figure it out. Anybody has any idea?

Comment: _"I can clearly see that all origin_id are included"_ – what about the 5 extra tickets, do you see their origin_ids values? And do they differ from the origin_ids in your query?

Comment: *"How to use $in with Mongoid?"* - You are using it correctly in both instances so the issue is likely your data not your usage.

Comment: hello @Stefan, I've printed the `origin_id` on screen and they are different from the ids I'm querying, it's extremely odd and I don't have an explanation. It's really doing a select *.